# hibernate connection pool with mysql and tomcat 7

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat7

I am stuck in this problem since last 5 days but couldn't find any proper solution.

I have added `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true` also with mysql connection url.

> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.io.EOFException
>
> STACKTRACE:
>
> java.io.EOFException
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1865)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2256)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2756)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1536)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1626)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3031)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:943)
>   at

Comment: hibernate c3p0 configuration as  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
   <property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>

Comment: Add your comment data to the question.